# calling a JS function without any event in the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a page which contains the following code.

```
<style>
.objects {display: inline-table; width: 180px; height: 180px;  border-radius: 50%; transition: transform .4s;}
.objects:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
.objects:after {content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; width:180px; height: 180px; z-index: -1; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.objects, .objects:after { width: 20vw; height: 20vw;}
}
.objects p { text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; visibility: hidden; color: black; z-index: 100; position: relative;} 
#object1{background-color: brown;} 
#object2{background-color: red;} 
#object3{background-color: yellow;} 
#object4{background-color: blue;}
#object5{background-color: green;}
#object6{background-color: black;}
</style>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around;margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:100px;">
<div id="object1" class="objects" onmouseover="nomeIn(this)" onmouseout="nomeOut(this)" >
<p>brick brown</p>
</div>
<div id="object2" class="objects" onmouseover="nomeIn(this)" onmouseout="nomeOut(this)" >
<p>brick red</p>
</div>
<div id="object3" class="objects" onmouseover="nomeIn(this)" onmouseout="nomeOut(this)">
<p>brick melange</p>
</div>
</div>


<script>
function nomeIn(object){
  let selettore = "#" + object.id + " p";
  document.querySelector(selettore).style.visibility = "visible";
}
function nomeOut(object){
  let selettore = "#" + object.id + " p";
  document.querySelector(selettore).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>
```

This page works properly, as you can see in the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/B612/xnqu3frd/):

However, for some reasons, one of the plugins I have in my site keeps erasing all the events from the html code, so I can't use "onmouseover" and "onmouseout".

Without these events in the html, I can't call the function and I should write a different JS code, which would be similar to this:

```
document.querySelector(".objects").onmouseover = function nomeIn(){
let selector = "#" + this.id + " p";
document.querySelector(selector).style.visibility = "visible";
}
document.querySelector(".objects").onmouseout = function nomeOut(){ 
let selector = "#" + this.id + " p";
document.querySelector(selector).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

However, in this case, the mouseover would work only with the first circular element (the text would appear only in the first circle): [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/B612/36odb5vw/1/)

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: _"would work only with the first circular element"_ - Because that's how `.querySelector()` works. You might want to have a look at `.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Why do you use JS for this? `.objects p { visibility: hidden } .objects:hover p { visibility: visible }` (especially when you already have such a rule for: `.objects:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }`): https://jsfiddle.net/9ru6ceyk/

Comment: Thanks Andreas. In the end your pure CSS solution was the best one I could use; however I enjoyed very much the explanation about the querySelectorAll()... Probably when I programmed it, I was too tired :P

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second code, you are using `document.querySelector` to select the `.objects` divs. This function always return the **first** element encountered. To solve this, you could use the `document.querySelectorAll` function and iterate through each element:

```js
[ ...document.querySelectorAll(".objects") ].forEach(element => {
  element.onmouseover = function () {
     let selector = "#" + this.id + " p";
     document.querySelector(selector).style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  element.onmouseout = function () { 
    let selector = "#" + this.id + " p";
    document.querySelector(selector).style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
});
```